# If two men could have a baby (e.g. via stem cells), would it be haram?

Tags: fiqh, science, baby

This is new research that could take a stem cell and make it into a sperm or an egg. So, it's plausible that we could take the stem cell from one man and make that into an egg and fertilize the egg with the sperm from the other man. This can then be placed inside of a woman and she can give birth to the baby that is not genetically hers. The baby would be genetically derived from the two men. This is not a possibility yet, but could be in just a few years. Would this be haram?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's sperm goes inside the woman (*except her husband*) then this is haram. As touching, talking and even gazing any Na-Mehram is haram let alone putting sperms in her (*by any means*).

So, as to your question,"`If two men could have a baby (e.g. via stem cells), would it be haram?`".  Yes, it would obviously Haram.

Answer (score -2):

The act of growing the baby in another woman for straight couples is currently possible but is haram because that woman has labored for a child and it would not be fair to take it from her. Relatively I assume it would be the same for two men.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Unlike most internet forums we expect answers here to be well elaborated, focused and of your own words supported by evidences. Therefore I strongly recommend you to take our [tour], check our [help] and [meta] and read [anser] to learn more about how this site works!

Comment: @D.N Please back your claims from islamic sources and scholarly views. not just your opinions